# How do i remove "This view overlaps one of it's siblings" warning?

Tags: iphone

I'm getting the following warning:

***This view overlaps one of it's siblings***

How do i remove this warning?

regards
Jayaraj

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode, open the build settings for your target (or you can set it globally at the project level), type "xib" into the search field and you should see the "Show Warnings" option (IBC_WARNINGS).  I believe turning that off will muffle all NIB-related warnings.

In Interface Builder, you can open the preferences, go to Alerts and make "Illegal Geometry" a "Note" instead of a warning.

Comment: Does anyone know how to resolve this in the current version of XCode (8.2.1) - I can't find where this setting would be...